# Poner enlaces en la columna correspondiente

Tags: php, html

Estoy tratando de poner los .zip, .xml, .pdf para poderlas descargar esos archivos en sus respectivas columnas y tratar de ponerlos toda en una sola linea y que en la descripción solo salga sin las extensiones.

Este es el index.php:

```
<?php
        $listar = null;
        $directorio = opendir("../Prueba2/RUC/$ruc/FACTURAS");
        while($elemento = readdir($directorio)){
            if($elemento != '.' && $elemento != '..'){
                if(is_dir("Prueba2/".$elemento)){
                    //$listar .= "<li><a href='Prueba2/$elemento/' target='_blank'>$elemento</a></li>";
                    $listar .= "<li href='Prueba2/$elemento/'>$elemento</li>";
                }else{
                    //$listar .= "<li><a href='Prueba2/$elemento' target='_blank'>$elemento</a></li>";
                    $listar .= "<li href='Prueba2/$elemento'>$elemento</li>";
                }
            }
        }
   ?>



<?php
        //header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=''");
        //header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        //header("Content-Length: ");
        //readfile("");

        $listarZIP = null;
        $descargaZIP = opendir("../Prueba2/RUC/$ruc/FACTURAS");
        while($archivo = readdir($directorio)){
            if(is_dir($archivo)){
                echo "[".$archivo . "]<br/>";
                echo "<img src='Prueba2/RUC/$ruc/FACTURAS'>";
            }else{
                echo $archivo . "<br/>";
            }
        }
    ?>


<center>
        <h1>FACTURA</h1>
        <form action="logica/listado.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table border="1" width="90%">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width:70px">#</td>
                    <td>Descripción</td>
                    <td style="width:90px">ZIP</td>
                    <td style="width:90px">XML</td>
                    <td style="width:90px">PDF</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><? echo "" ?></td>
                    <td style="list-style:none;"><? echo $listar ?></td>
                    <td><? echo $listarZIP ?></td>
                    <td><? echo "" ?></td>   
                    <td><? echo "" ?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </center>
```

Este es el resultado por ahora...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado final sería así, en la descripción sin las extensiones y en las columnas con las extensiones que correspondan en una imagen...

```
#      Descripción                   ZIP                    XML              PDF  
1  /  20104624104-01-00001 /   20104624104-01-00001.zip  /20104624104-01-00001.xml  
2  /  20104624104-01-00002 /   20104624104-01-00002.zip  /20104624104-01-00002.xml
```

Omitan los slash "/" y al final es un PDF, todo eso vienen correlativos ya que son varias lineas. No entiendo como lo podría hacer...

Comment: Buenas, es recomendabre que cambies las imagenes de codigo por texto, las imagenes dificultan la lectura del codigo asi como copiarlo para hacer correcciones y por lo tanto habra menos gente que se moleste en ayudarte ya que las imagenes de codigo requieren una inversion te tiempo extra. Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, ya lo corregí para que así puedan entender mejor y copiar el código.